# Center align table as a whole in the middle of the page with HTML

Tags: html, alignment, center

What is the easiest way to center a whole table in the middle of a page with HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following CSS:

```
table {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it only with `HTML`.

`<center>` is only element that can do it, but is not preferred and is **deprecated**.

So you can use `CSS` for this.
just put the parent element's position to be `relative` and set horizontal margins of this element to be `auto`.

example :

```
<div id="parent">
    <table>
        ....
    </table>
</div>

#parent {
    position: relative;
}
table {
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Comment: The `#parent {position: relative;}` is unnecessary. So is the `px` after `0`.